# validation control in asp.net with masterpage buttons

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a lot of textboxes on submit page and all have a validator. I want to control them with a submit button which is on master page. It works but other buttons also cause validation. validation summary is always shown either submit button is clicked or any other buttons. how can I control this situation? (asp.net)

Answer (score 2):

for each individual submit use "ValidationGroup". here is the sample:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="Submit" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ValidationGroup="Submit" ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" ValidationGroup="Submit" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: I give that property to all controls but it doesn't work. button is on masterpage. so does it causes a problem?

Comment: can't you show some code? make sure you don't have similar ValidationGroup name for other buttons too.

Comment: ok. we solve the problem. I forgot to give same valur to validation summary :) thaks..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can resolve this by using ValidationGroup Property..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_imagebutton_validationgroup.asp

Thanks

Deepu

Comment: I tried that but doesn't work. button is on masterpage, controls are in inner page. Is it be the problem?